# "sich (an einem Ort) aufhalten" vs "der Aufenthalt"

Tags: etymology, spelling, grammaticality

Why is there the extra syllable "ent" in the noun?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Digitales Wörterbuch der Deutschen Sprache](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Aufenthalt) it originates from mhd. *ūfenthalt*, "place for staying", which is an extension of mhd. *enthalt*, which means "resting/standstill/end" (in modern German it changed its (verb) meaning to "contain" or reflexive "abstain")

The prefix [*ent-*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/ent-) in connection with verbs can express the beginning of a process (though this is now for modern German), so it could be related to a continued stopping, ie standstill. However, this is just my educated guess — etymology is often guesswork and usually not certain.

In the same dictionary there is no specific etymology given for *aufhalten*, so I guess this is just a straight forward modern combination of the prefix *auf-* with the stem *halten*. [*Auf-*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/auf-) can express the result or completion of an action, so by stopping someone/something they are then halted. Again the caveat here is that this is for modern German.

So while *Aufenthalt* and *aufhalten* both ultimately derive from *halten*, they have taken different paths in their etymological life.

Comment: DWDS does link the DWB. Which does not admit an etymology for *aufhalten*, but implicitly suggests a line of derivation. It also shows Dutch and Swedish comparands, so it's not "modern" at least.

Comment: @vectory Yes, "modern" is rather relative here. I meant in comparison to mhd.

Comment: err, yes, if the comparands reflect very different sense, you might be correct.

Comment: on another note, I'd like to compare *aufhören* (see *aufhalten* #7 in DWB) with *gehören*, *wo gehörst du hin?* to *aufenthalt*, perhaps also *Hort*, or Fr *arreter*, Lat *arrest-*, *rest-* (i.e. En *to rest*), assuming rhotazism *l* ~ *r*. That was asked about [over at Ling.SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/34566/when-turned-to-hear-into-to-belong-in-germanic-languages/34598#34598). semantic related *belong* is uncertain as well.